# Solve differential equation $x'+2x+(t+1)x^2=\frac{1}{(t+1)^2}-\frac{1}{t+1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Solve $$x'+2x+(t+1)x^2=\frac{1}{(t+1)^2}-\frac{1}{t+1}$$

This looks like Ricati's eqution so we need to guess some solution. But I cannot find any.

Comment: Hint: $x(t)=-\frac{1}{t+1}$ is one solution

Comment: it is a Ricacati equation